# C++ : class classname :: reference { ... }

Tags: c++, stl, reference

I was learning stl and never saw this kind of class like `class classname :: reference {}`

I searched on the net but could get good information ..

```
class bitset::reference {
  friend class bitset;
  reference();                                 // no public constructor
public:
  ~reference();
  operator bool () const;                      // convert to bool
  reference& operator= ( bool x );             // assign from bool
  reference& operator= ( const reference& x ); // assign from bit
  reference& flip();                           // flip bit value
  bool operator~() const;                      // return inverse value
};
```

- what is this :: reference here for ?

i saw this code here[enter link description here][1]
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/
i have worked on c++ before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the bitset class definition? There is something like this somewhere:

```
template<size_t _Bits>
class bitset
{
    ...
    class reference;
    ...
}
```

It's much like putting the body of a funciton outside the class body. Now we are putting the body of a nested class outside of the parent class:

```
class bitset::reference
{
    /* class body */
}
```

By the way, in MSVC (`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\bitset`) the're actually defined inside each other:

```
// TEMPLATE CLASS bitset
template<size_t _Bits>
class bitset
{   // store fixed-length sequence of Boolean elements
typedef unsigned long _Ty;  // base type for a storage word
enum {digits = _Bits};  // extension: compile-time size()

public:
typedef bool element_type;  // retained

    // CLASS reference
class reference
    {   // proxy for an element
    friend class bitset<_Bits>;
    .
    .
    .
```

It's the same for g++'s `bitset.h`, although a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1):

reference is class name, nothing special. bitset::reference means that reference is internal class.

Answer (score 1):

The line right before the snippet you quoted explains:

> Because no such small elemental type exists in most C++ environments, the individual elements are accessed as special references which mimic bool elements

C++ does not allow references to bitfields, so the `reference` class is used to simulate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [nested class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23h0937%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). From the article:

> A class can be declared within the scope of another class. Such a
>   class is called a "nested class." Nested classes are considered to be
>   within the scope of the enclosing class and are available for use
>   within that scope. To refer to a nested class from a scope other than
>   its immediate enclosing scope, you must use a fully qualified name.

An alternative interpretation is that the `bitset` class is being used not only as a class but as a namespace as well.